# EosioSwiftVault - SecKeyCreateWithData always returns nil in iOS 17

Tags: eosio-code, security, ios

When I'm trying to create SecKey with EosioSwiftVault library using SecKeyCreateWithData it returns nil in iOS 17 (it's still working fine on iOS 16.4) with following error:

```
var attributes: [String: Any] = [ kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom, kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate, kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256, kSecAttrAccessGroup as String: accessGroup, kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true, kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: [ kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true, kSecAttrAccessControl as String: access ] ] 

guard let secKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(privateKey as CFData, attributes as CFDictionary, &error) else { print(error.debugDescription) throw EosioError(.keyManagementError, reason: error.debugDescription) }

Optional(Swift.Unmanaged<__C.CFErrorRef>(_value: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "EC private key creation from data failed" UserInfo={numberOfErrorsDeep=0, NSDescription=EC private key creation from data failed}))
```

privateKey is base64Encoded Data `BNcHWtSeaQzOjwoHakZ66ojCFZV4uGU+VjRSAMOxd2NpwAEXHOarCV3yonOyJI5UIkJ1CCO+DbORtG83DDMkNuVmPGQu5nJiQCD9RfDA+UncG+woRrTrLDhAw6fHXD9DtA==`

Any other options of creating a SecKey or the possible resolution of this problem? It's became critical for our organization cause we cannot proceed with storage process and EOS accounts are becoming unavailable for all our users.